# Controller/Action from Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

This seems to be a popular issue but I could not find a solution from earlier posts.
I am trying to call action 'charge' in controller 'donate'

My url is like this

```
mysite.com/test/
```

routing is like

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
        routes.Add(
            new Route("history/buildings/{id}/{action}/{controller}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(
            new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = "home" }),
            new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
                );
        routes.Add(
              new Route("donate/{action}/{id}",
              new RouteValueDictionary(
              new { controller = "donate", action = "index", id = "donate" }),
              new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
            );
        routes.Add(
            new Route("{id}/{action}/{controller}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(
            new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = "index" }),
            new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
        );
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/test/donate/charge", 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(myData),
```

this goes to

```
mysite.com/donate/charge
```

which looks right but gives me a 404 (looking at the network traffic in dev tools)

The action is

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult charge (WebSiteSessions.order ord)
```

I have tried both the JsonResult and an ActionResult but same problem

I imagine its something stupid - help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have a `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Charge(...)` method in `DonateController`? (you need the show the relevant code)

Comment: yes - just added it above

Comment: I cannot understand what your trying to do with those route definitions - why do you have a segment for `{id}` that would add 'donate'? (and ditto for `id = "index"` in the last one). Did you mean to make it `id = UrlParameter.Optional` rather than `id = "donate"`?

Comment: And you should always be using `url: '@Url.Action("Charge", "Donate")',` to ensure your url's are correctly generated

Comment: maybe not the most elegant way but I use id (page name) to do a page lookup.  All pages except pages like this donate page use index/index.

Comment: Does the url: @url ... need to be on the page? I tried that but the jquery was on a linked page and didn't work -let me try that

Comment: Do you mean that script is in an external js file (in which case you need to assign the url in the view and pass it to the external file)

Comment: yes it was an external file - I just moved it onto the page using the @url... that seems to have gotten rid of the error - Thanks - but not sure if the action is firing or not yet - didn't get the results I was looking for yet, but looks like I'm past the issue